# Java memory leak multithreading

Tags: java, memory-leaks

This is a small service which is leaking somewhere. Recently I've refactored my code where I've added parallel job execution and after release noticed that my heap is growing and GC is not able to free application memory.

I am including only small part of the code which has been changed and releasing that bit made a leak possible.

**What the code does?** its really simple - this is a small web endpoint which as a parameter gets customer cookie and executes two jobs in parallel. (right now only one) Combines results from both jobs and return back to client. Job is straight forward as well, go redis, get customer id, go another service and get information about current customer, identify gender by customer name, return results.

That would be really helpful if you could quickly walk though code and let me know if you spot anything which might cause a potential memory leak.

```
@Service
public class PersonalisationService {


    private static final org.slf4j.Logger InfoLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("InfoLogger");
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger ErrorLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ErrorLogger");

    @Autowired
    private TimeLimiter timeLimiter;

    @Autowired
    private RedisRepository redisRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RESTRepository restRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GenderService genderService;

    @Autowired
    private SQLRepository sqlRepository;



    public PersonalisationData runGeneralPersonalisation(final String customerCookie, Long timeout) throws PersonalisationException, CustomerNotFoundException, UncheckedTimeoutException {

        GeneralPersonalisationWrapper generalPersonalisationWrapper =
                new GeneralPersonalisationWrapper();

        return generalPersonalisationWrapper.run(customerCookie, timeout);
    }



    class GeneralPersonalisationWrapper {
        private GeneralPersonalisationHandler generalPersonalisationHandler;

        public PersonalisationData run(final String customerCookie, Long timeout) throws PersonalisationException {
            try {
                ResourceStack resourceStack = new ResourceStack();
                resourceStack.setGenderService(genderService);
                resourceStack.setRedisRepository(redisRepository);
                resourceStack.setRestRepository(restRepository);
                resourceStack.setSqlRepository(sqlRepository);

                final Timeout t = new Timeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                generalPersonalisationHandler = new GeneralPersonalisationHandler(resourceStack);
                com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult result = timeLimiter.callWithTimeout(new Callable<com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult call() throws Exception {
                        com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult result = generalPersonalisationHandler.runAndAwaitResults(customerCookie);
                        generalPersonalisationHandler.shutdown();
                        return result;
                    }
                }, timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true);

                PersonalisationData response = transformAvailableResults(result);
                return response;
            } catch (UncheckedTimeoutException e) {
                String errorMsg = String.format("TIMEOUT for RunGeneralPersonalisation() execution time has exceeded maximum limit of: [%s] ms", timeout);
                ErrorLogger.error(errorMsg, e);
                com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult result = generalPersonalisationHandler.returnAvailableResults();
                generalPersonalisationHandler.shutdown();
                return transformAvailableResults(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new PersonalisationException(e);
            }
        }
}
}
```

GeneralPersonalisationHandler.java

```
public class GeneralPersonalisationHandler {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger InfoLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("InfoLogger");
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger ErrorLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ErrorLogger");

    private GeneralPersonalisationResult generalPersonalisationResult;

    private final int SUBMITTED_JOBS = 1;
    private CompletionService<JobResult> completionService;
    private ResourceStack resourceStack;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    public GeneralPersonalisationHandler(ResourceStack resourceStack){
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(SUBMITTED_JOBS);
        this.completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<JobResult>(executor);
        this.resourceStack = resourceStack;
    }

    public GeneralPersonalisationResult runAndAwaitResults(String customerCookie) throws Exception {

        Job customerEventsJob = new CustomerEventsJob(customerCookie, resourceStack);
        Job customerInfoJob = new CustomerPersonalInfoJob(customerCookie, resourceStack);

        completionService.submit(customerInfoJob);
        //completionService.submit(customerEventsJob);


        generalPersonalisationResult = new GeneralPersonalisationResult();
        for (int handledJobs = 0; handledJobs < SUBMITTED_JOBS; handledJobs++) {
            Future<JobResult> result = completionService.take();

            JobResult jobResult = result.get();
            if (jobResult instanceof CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult) {
                CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult customerPersonalInfoJobResult = (CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult) jobResult;
                generalPersonalisationResult.setCustomerPersonalInfoJobResult(customerPersonalInfoJobResult);
            }

            if (jobResult instanceof CustomerEventsJobResult) {
                CustomerEventsJobResult customerEventsJobResult = (CustomerEventsJobResult) jobResult;
                generalPersonalisationResult.setCustomerEventsJobResult(customerEventsJobResult);
            }
        }

        return generalPersonalisationResult;
    }

    public GeneralPersonalisationResult returnAvailableResults(){
        return this.generalPersonalisationResult;
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        if(!this.executor.isShutdown()) {
            this.executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerPersonalInfoJob.java

```
public class CustomerPersonalInfoJob extends Job {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger InfoLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("InfoLogger");
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger ErrorLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ErrorLogger");

    private String cookie;
    private RedisRepository redisRepository;
    private GenderService genderService;
    private SQLRepository sqlRepository;
    private RESTRepository restRepository;

    public CustomerPersonalInfoJob(String customerCookie, ResourceStack resourceStack){
        this.cookie = customerCookie;
        this.redisRepository = resourceStack.getRedisRepository();
        this.genderService = resourceStack.getGenderService();
        this.sqlRepository = resourceStack.getSqlRepository();
        this.restRepository = resourceStack.getRestRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult call() throws Exception {

        Long customerId = null;
        try {
            customerId =redisRepository.getCustomerId(cookie);
        }
        catch (RedisRepositoryException e){
            ErrorLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        CustomerDetails customerDetails = null;
        try{
            customerDetails =restRepository.getCustomerInfo(customerId);
        }catch (RESTRepositoryException e){
            ErrorLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        Gender gender = Gender.UNKNOWN;
        try{
            gender = determineGender(customerDetails);
        }catch (GenderServiceException e){
            ErrorLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult result = new CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult();
        result.setCustomerDetails(customerDetails);
        result.setGender(gender);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to debug memory leaks - I would suggest you recreate and take a heap dump. Then analyse it and see what's taking up space.  Might be worth comparing that with a similar heap dump taken before the changes.

Comment: I think a "full code review" should better go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ And instead of relying on the eyes of others, you might consider to run a profiler to understand more exactly where/when problems occur.

Comment: Solving **known** problems (including *known* memory leaks) is outside the scope of [codereview.se].